# Favicon only showing up in Chrome

Tags: html, webpack

Here you're seeing Chrome, Firefox, and IE (with clean history) opening the same page:

[image]

I'm using Webpack and this is how I inserted the favicon:

**webpack.dev.conf.js:**

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: 'index.html',
  favicon: 'favicon.ico',
  template: 'src/index.html',
  inject: true
})
```

**webpack.prod.conf.js:**

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: '../index.html',
  favicon: 'favicon.ico',
  template: 'src/index.html',
  inject: true,
  minify: {
    // minify code
```

Output: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico">` which opens fine: http://vrviewer.istaging.co/static/favicon.ico

I'm really confused.

Here's a live example: http://vrviewer.istaging.co/#!/564810

**EDIT:** The A favicon is the favicon of one of my npm modules: https://aframe.io/. I have no idea how it gets there, though.

**EDIT 2:** I placed the favicon in the root folder I cleaned the browser cache but I'm still having the same problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers doesn't register rel="shortcut icon" at all.

Put the favicon.ico in the root of your domain so that browsers will find it by default all the time.

Source: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't work. Please see my edit.

Comment: @alex, you need to put the file under the folder public.  I try the http://vrviewer.istaging.co/favicon.ico and it is not working.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I uploaded the icon to the public folder: http://vrviewer.istaging.co/favicon.ico. Same problem. Maybe the aframe npm module is somehow overriding the icon in Firefox and IE?

Comment: @alex - Try refreshing your browser and clear cache. It works for me on Win 7 machine (FF, Chrome, IE) [http://s32.postimg.org/uwreoi479/test.jpg]

Comment: Oh, I just realized the favicon shows up if you omit `564810` from the link I posted. But the aframe one appears if you inclue it. Werid.

Comment: @alex - The link you posted (564810) contains the following code -> <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="https://aframe.io/images/aframe-logo-192.png">.  That is what causing the icon red with white A outline.

Comment: yes, I opened the issue at Github: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/1450#issuecomment-220213425. Thanks for the help anyways! (At least now I have the icon in the root URL).